# Traveling in Red Dead Redemption

Tags: red-dead-redemption

Currently to quickly travel to a waypoint on the map I have to do this:

1. Set the waypoint
2. Create a camp
3. Click "Travel to waypoint"

Is there a better way to fast travel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That does seem to be the fastest way. You could also try riding as a passenger in one of the stagecoaches set up on the edge of one of the towns.

Alternately, in free roam you can go to one of the wagon wheel markers in a settlement, but that works pretty much the same way.